# How to insert a search button in the input box

Tags: html, css

What I am trying to achieve is to add a circular shaped search button at the end of the input, but somehow I am not getting the logic to how to do so. I am using Font Awesome as a font displaying for the icons.

```css
.search-box {
  outline: none;
  padding: 7px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-color: transparent;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firefox, other Gecko */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="Search For a Product..">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot place a `<button>` (or any other element) within an `<input>`. However you can 'fake' it, by having a containing element which looks like the input. You can then position the button to the right of the input with the required CSS styling to make it appear round. Try this:

```css
.search-container {
  background-color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 3px 50px 3px 10px;
}
.search-box {
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.search-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 4px;
  top: 4px;
  background-color: #C00;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  outline: 0;
}

body {
  background: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<br /><br /><br />

<div class="search-container">
  <input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="Search For a Product..">
  <button class="search-button">Go</button>
</div>
```

Comment: it should be inside the input element not outside :(

Comment: @AkshayShrivastav you cannot place a button within an input

Comment: @AkshayShrivastav you didn't mention in the question that you need the button inside the input

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan hmmm can't that be achieved with `z-Index` ? sure it won't be perfect but ...

Comment: @niceman it could, but it would overlap the end of the `input`, and hide the text.

Comment: your answer is better than what I said :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan your code worked perfectly what i wanted. :D thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will help you with your idea of creating button inside a text box.

```css
/*Clearing Floats*/
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}

.cf {
  zoom: 1;
}


/* Form wrapper styling */
.form-wrapper {
  width: 450px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 150px auto 50px auto;
  background: #444;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}


/* Form text input */

.form-wrapper input {
  width: 330px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  float: left;
  font: bold 15px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
  border: 0;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.form-wrapper input:focus {
  outline: 0;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) inset;
}

.form-wrapper input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #999;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
}

.form-wrapper input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
}

.form-wrapper input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #999;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
}


/* Form submit button */

.form-wrapper button {
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 40px;
  width: 110px;
  font: bold 15px/40px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #d83c3c;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.form-wrapper button:hover {
  background: #e54040;
}

.form-wrapper button:active,
.form-wrapper button:focus {
  background: #c42f2f;
  outline: 0;
}

.form-wrapper button:before {
  /* left arrow */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-width: 8px 8px 8px 0;
  border-style: solid solid solid none;
  border-color: transparent #d83c3c transparent;
  top: 12px;
  left: -6px;
}

.form-wrapper button:hover:before {
  border-right-color: #e54040;
}

.form-wrapper button:focus:before,
.form-wrapper button:active:before {
  border-right-color: #c42f2f;
}

.form-wrapper button::-moz-focus-inner {
  /* remove extra button spacing for Mozilla Firefox */
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-wrapper cf">
  <input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="Search For a Product..">
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4betjLb1/)

[Source](https://speckyboy.com/how-to-build-a-stylish-css3-search-box/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title> Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-animation.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      .search-box {
      outline: none;
      padding: 7px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-right: 40px;
      height: 35px;
      width: 90%;
      border-radius: 30px;
      font-size: 15px;
      border-color: transparent;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firefox, other Gecko */
      box-sizing: border-box; /* Opera/IE 8+ */
      }

      #filtersubmit {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
      left: -25px;
      top: 1px;
      color: black;
      cursor:pointer;
      width: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <br><br>
    <div class="container">
      <input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="Search For a Product..">
      <i id="filtersubmit" class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps.

​